# OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace with Orika 1.5.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, orika

I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace error after running my Spring boot program for few days. Memory profiling showed the issue is in Orika library. This is how I used Orika in my app. I guess I have used orika in wrong manner.

In controller

```
ChangePropertyRequest changePropertyRequest
                    = OrikaMapperFactory.getMapperFactory(OrikaMapperFactory.OrikaMapper.CHANGE_PROPERTY_REQUEST_FACTORY)
                    .map(changePropRequestMsg.getChangePropRequestMsg().getValue().getChangePropertyRequest().getValue(), ChangePropertyRequest.class);
```

In OrikaMapperFactory

```
public interface OrikaMapperFactory {
    static MapperFacade getMapperFactory(@NotNull OrikaMapper orikaMapper) {
        switch (orikaMapper) {
            case CHANGE_PROPERTY_REQUEST_FACTORY:
                return changePropertyRequestMapperFactory();         
           
            default:
                return defaultMapperFacade();
        }
    }

    enum OrikaMapper {
        CHANGE_PROPERTY_REQUEST_FACTORY
    }

}
```

In OrikaMapperFactoryImpl

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class OrikaMapperFactoryImpl implements OrikaMapperFactory {

    private static final MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();


    public static MapperFacade defaultMapperFacade() {
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }

    static {
        final ConverterFactory converterFactory = mapperFactory.getConverterFactory();
        converterFactory.registerConverter("resultHeaderConverter", new ResultHeaderToResultHeaderXsd());
    }

public static MapperFacade changePropertyRequestMapperFactory() {
        mapperFactory.classMap(ChangePropertyRequest.class, com.dto.ChangePropertyRequest.class)
                .field("userId.value", "userId")
                .field("commonProperty.value.accountCode.value", "commonProperty.accountCode")
                .byDefault()
                .register();
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }
```

Comment: And the problem you found was?

Comment: There were set of Orika related classes in heap after calling this particular controller method several times.  Even after GC pause it not get cleared and heap memory was getting increasing with each call.